# MEF how to get previous instance when part creation policy is non-shared

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mef

I have an `ItemListViewModel` and an `ItemDefViewModel` in my program. The `ItemDefViewModel` will handle editing any data in an item while the `ItemListViewModel` class provides an overview and provides a command to instantiate a new `ItemDefViewModel`. 
I am testing now and I have tested the `ItemDefViewModel` without much trouble. I am using MEF and am creating the `ItemDefViewModel` with `CreationPolicy` as non-shared. The `ItemListViewModel` internally acquires a new `ItemDefViewModel` via the container and calls the `AddItem` function on it when the command to add a new item is executed. Changing data of this new item is done in the `ItemDefViewModel` but I can't get a handle to it because of its creation policy. Any way to get around this?

Comment: please explain why do you need a handle to previous instance? If I understood, you already have a collection of ItemDefViewModel stored in ItemsListViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to persist your instances of `ItemDefViewModel` somewhere (which as @JohnPolvora has noted you are already doing in your `ItemListViewModel`).

If you can't do that, you will need to persist the state of that view model, and restore it back to the new instance of `ItemDefViewModel` before then applying your changes.